# VMWare ESXi 5.x - Megaraid controller and SMIS - correct way to monitor/manage controller?

Tags: vmware-esxi, monitoring, megaraid, megacli

I found some information online: [How to Enable RAID Monitoring and Configuration under ESXi 5.x](http://kb.stonegroup.co.uk/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=195) as well as here on ServerFault here: [How can I get an email alert when RAID array is degraded? VMware ESXi 5.0, MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i](https://serverfault.com/questions/350750/how-can-i-get-an-email-alert-when-raid-array-is-degraded-vmware-esxi-5-0-megar)

My question is basically this:

**What is the proper way on an ESXi host with an LSI Megaraid SAS controller to manage the controller's health and be able to use the LSI Megaraid Manager software remotely as well as get email alerts?**

I can get into the CIMC/ILO on the hosts to get controller health as well, but I'd like to be able to properly see this and alert within vCenter.  We are a Windows centric shop so I'd prefer to use the MSM tools remotely rather than megacli directly on the host if possible.

Are the above links the proper wait to handle this?

Or is there another way that I'm missing in my research?  I don't want to make the above changes to an esxi host only to find out it isn't the proper answer to my question in bold above.

Comment: It's a tricky area. What type of servers are these?

Comment: Most are Cisco UCS C Series - either 220 or 240 (M3 and M4).

Comment: Any luck with this: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004166 
Although it does say - No support is available for the controller health information.